# Why do I see some .py applications listed (Get-Command) but not others?

Tags: powershell

If I run the `Get-Command` cmdlet, included in the list displayed are a small number of my own .py programs. These programs are all in one location on my system, but are just a tiny proportion of the total .py programs on the system, none of these others are listed.

They are listed as applications and will now run from a call from PowerShell from any working directory.

Can anyone tell me why this would be? And how I could add other programs to be recognised as applications.

Comment: Show `$env:path` and `$env:pathext`.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem C:\ -Include *.py -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory -Unique` will list all folders in `C:` where you have `.py` files : )

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. I can see from this that the .py files that PS is recognizing are included in the $env paths.